# Backup and restore site collection without their data

Tags: 2013, administration, central-administration, backup, restore

I have finished my implementation and testing on the staging server, and now I want to back-up then restore my two site collections inside the production server. But when I did the same step from development  to staging the back-up and restore moved the site collection date as well. But on production server I need to move both site collection without any data (completely fresh copies). Any idea how I can do such a process ?. Baring in mind that I do the backup using the site administrator UI , and I do the restore by using the following command:-

```
Restore-spsite -identity http//the siteURL…… -path C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\25-9\g -force
```

Comment: You do know that Date and Data are two different things? :)

Comment: :) change it to date ..